# Am I getting serverless function timeouts (error 504) on vercel because I set up next-auth wrong?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, vercel, next-auth

### Background

I've been working on a next.js project that is meant to handle scheduling events. I've been using next-auth for authentication with mongodb, because I need a database to store information about scheduled events anyway.

While testing locally, I didn't have any issues at all, but ever since deploying on vercel AND mongo Atlas, I've been getting 504 "serverless function timeouts" up the wazoo on page load. A lot of people have mentioned that this is likely due to not making a connection with the db, but I'm not sure how to fix this. The only function that I am calling inside of getServerSideProps is getSession() as it is called in the docs.

### Steps I've tried

- I've followed the next-auth configuration steps located [here](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/mongodb) for mongodb
- I've followed the mongodb guide for vercel best practices [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/best-practices-connecting-from-vercel/)
- I've tried connecting to the atlas from the mongosh shell, and it's always quick as can be.

### Conclusion

I've seen some stuff around mentioning that other people have been getting some pretty wicked cold start times on their serverless function, so I've created a snippet that pings the home page of my app 10 times every 2 minutes. This works okay as far as I can personally test, but 4-5 of any 10 requests hang for 10+ seconds while the rest finish up in roughly 200ms or so.

What am I doing wrong? / What can I do better?

### My code

home page:

```js
export const Home = function (props) { ... } // this never gets ran

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  const props = { session };
  const redirect = {
    destination: '/login',
    permanent: false,
  };

  return (!session)
    ? { redirect }
    : { props };
}

export default Home;
```

The login page:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/home',
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      providers: await getProviders(),
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

nextAuth config:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { MongoDBAdapter } from '@next-auth/mongodb-adapter';
import clientPromise from 'lib/database/mongodb';

export default NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: "pshhhh, it's a secret" 
});
```

Comment: I was the same as you, using Mongodb Atlas (with mongoose), all setup properly. Everything works fine in dev (both next dev and vercel dev) but fail on Vercel. If I remove `getServerSideProps` then it works 100% of the time on vercel. If I add it back the issue comes back. Looks to me like a bug on vercel ‍♂️.